# What is the query required for fetching full-text with delimiter in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Assuming I have a document like this in elasticSearch :

```
{
  "videoName": "taylor.mp4",
  "type": "long"
}
```

I tried full-text search using the DSL query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match":{
            "videoName": "taylor"
        }
    }
}
```

I need to get the above document, but I don't get it .If I specify **taylor.mp4**, it returns the document.

So, I would like to know, how to make full-text search with delimiters.

**Edit after KARTHEEK answer:**

The **regexp** fetches the **taylor.mp4** document. Take the situation, where the document in video index are:

```
{
  "videoName": "Akon - smack that.mp4",
  "type": "long"
}
```

So, the query for retrieving this document can be ,

```
{
    "query": {
        "match":{
            "videoName": "smack that"
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, the document will be retrieved, since we use **smack** in the query string. **match** does the full-text search and gets us the document. But, say I only know the **that** keyword and the **match**, doesn't get the document. I need to use **regexp** for that.

```
{
    "query": {
        "regexp":{
            "videoName": "smack.* that.*"
        }
    }
}
```

On the Other hand, if i take up **regexp** and make all my query strings to **smack.* that.***, this will also not retrieve any documents. And, we dont know which word will have its suffix **.mp4**. So, my question is we need to do the full-text search with **match**, and it should also detect the delimiters. Is there any other way ?

**Edit after Richa asked the mapping of index**

for **http://localhost:9200/example/videos/_mapping**

```
{
  "example": {
    "mappings": {
      "videos": {
        "properties": {
          "query": {
            "properties": {
              "match": {
                "properties": {
                  "videoName": {
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "type": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "videoName": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share the mapping of your index. `GET index_name/type_name/_mapping`

Comment: Updated the question with **mapping**

Answer (score 2):

Depending upon above query you mentioned right we can use regular expression in order get the result.Please find attached result for your perusal and let me know if there are anything else you want.

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/test/sample/_search" -d'
{
  "query": { 
    "regexp":{
        "videoName": "taylor.*"
    }
  }
}'

Result:

{
  "took": 22,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "sample",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "videoName": "taylor.mp4",
          "type": "long"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the **regexp** one, But i have some more questions. Have a look at my edited answer

Answer (score 2):

Please use this mapping

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "videoName": {
               "type": "string",
               "term_vector": "yes"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

After that you need to index a document that you mentioned earlier:

```
PUT test_index/doc/1
{
  "videoName": "Akon - smack that.mp4",
  "type": "long"
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.15342641,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test_index",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.15342641,
        "_source": {
          "videoName": "Akon - smack that.mp4",
          "type": "long"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Query to get results:

```
GET /test_index/doc/1/_termvector?fields=videoName
```

Results:

```
{
  "_index": "test_index",
  "_type": "doc",
  "_id": "1",
  "_version": 1,
  "found": true,
  "took": 1,
  "term_vectors": {
    "videoName": {
      "field_statistics": {
        "sum_doc_freq": 3,
        "doc_count": 1,
        "sum_ttf": 3
      },
      "terms": {
        "akon": {
          "term_freq": 1
        },
        "smack": {
          "term_freq": 1
        },
        "that.mp4": {
          "term_freq": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

By using this we will search based on "smack"

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "_all": "smack"
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.15342641,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test_index",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.15342641,
        "_source": {
          "videoName": "Akon - smack that.mp4",
          "type": "long"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```